# C++ CreateDIBitmap return null if move windows

Tags: c++, opencv, winapi, bitmap

I'm writing a demo program to load an image from file to OpenCV cv::Mat format, then convert to bitmap and display in Win32 windows. This is full source code:

```
// Win32
#include <Windows.h>

// OpenCV
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>
#pragma comment(lib, "opencv_core310d.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "opencv_imgcodecs310d.lib")

// Marco
#define WIN_CLASS_NAME  TEXT("DisplayTest")
#define WIN_NAME        TEXT("Display Test")
#define IMAGE_SRC       "./image.jpg"

// Global object
cv::Mat imgMat;
HWND hwndWindow;

// Convert cv::Mat data to bitmap
HBITMAP ConvertCVMatToBMP(cv::Mat frame)
{
    auto convertOpenCVBitDepthToBits = [](const INT32 value) {
        auto regular = 0u;

        switch (value) {
            case CV_8U:
            case CV_8S:
                regular = 8u;
                break;

            case CV_16U:
            case CV_16S:
                regular = 16u;
                break;

            case CV_32S:
            case CV_32F:
                regular = 32u;
                break;

            case CV_64F:
                regular = 64u;
                break;

            default:
                regular = 0u;
                break;
        }

        return regular;
    };

    auto imageSize = frame.size();

    if (imageSize.width && imageSize.height) {
        auto headerInfo = BITMAPINFOHEADER{};
        ZeroMemory(&headerInfo, sizeof(headerInfo));

        headerInfo.biSize = sizeof(headerInfo);
        headerInfo.biWidth = imageSize.width;
        headerInfo.biHeight = -(imageSize.height); // negative otherwise it will be upsidedown
        headerInfo.biPlanes = 1;// must be set to 1 as per documentation frame.channels();

        const auto bits = convertOpenCVBitDepthToBits(frame.depth());
        headerInfo.biBitCount = frame.channels() * bits;

        auto bitmapInfo = BITMAPINFO{};
        ZeroMemory(&bitmapInfo, sizeof(bitmapInfo));

        bitmapInfo.bmiHeader = headerInfo;
        bitmapInfo.bmiColors->rgbBlue = 0;
        bitmapInfo.bmiColors->rgbGreen = 0;
        bitmapInfo.bmiColors->rgbRed = 0;
        bitmapInfo.bmiColors->rgbReserved = 0;

        auto dc = GetDC(nullptr);
        assert(dc != nullptr && "Failure to get DC");

        auto bmp = CreateDIBitmap(dc,
                                  &headerInfo,
                                  CBM_INIT,
                                  frame.data,
                                  &bitmapInfo,
                                  DIB_RGB_COLORS);
        assert(bmp != nullptr && "Failure creating bitmap from captured frame");

        DeleteDC(dc);
        return bmp;
    }

    return nullptr;

}

// Attach image to windows
void attachImage()
{
    HBITMAP bitImage = (HBITMAP)ConvertCVMatToBMP(imgMat);

    // Display image
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hwndWindow, &ps);

    HDC imageDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
    BITMAP bm;
    HBITMAP imageBmpOld = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(imageDC, (HGDIOBJ)bitImage);

    GetObject(bitImage, sizeof(bm), &bm);

    BitBlt(
        hdc,         // tell it we want to draw to the screen
        0, 0,            // as position 0,0 (upper-left corner)
        (int)bm.bmWidth,   // width of the rect to draw
        (int)bm.bmHeight,   // height of the rect
        imageDC,        // the DC to get the rect from (our image DC)
        0, 0,            // take it from position 0,0 in the image DC
        SRCCOPY         // tell it to do a pixel-by-pixel copy
    );
    SelectObject(imageDC, (HGDIOBJ)imageBmpOld);
    DeleteDC(imageDC);
    DeleteObject((HGDIOBJ)imageBmpOld);
    EndPaint(hwndWindow, &ps);
}

// WndProc callback
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam)
{
    switch (message) {
        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;

        case WM_PAINT:
            attachImage();
            break;

        default:
            return (DefWindowProc(hwnd, message, wparam, lparam));
    }
}

// Register class
ATOM MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance)
{
    WNDCLASS wc = { 0 };
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH);
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(hInstance, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(hInstance, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wc.lpszClassName = WIN_CLASS_NAME;
    wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;

    return RegisterClass(&wc);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // Register class
    char t[500];
    GetConsoleTitleA(t, 500);
    HWND hwndConsole = FindWindowA(NULL, t);
    HINSTANCE hInstance = (HINSTANCE)GetWindowLong(hwndConsole, GWL_HINSTANCE);
    MyRegisterClass(hInstance);

    // Init data
    imgMat = cv::imread(IMAGE_SRC);

    // Create Win32 windows
    hwndWindow = CreateWindow(WIN_CLASS_NAME, WIN_NAME, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW ^ WS_THICKFRAME,
                              CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, CW_USEDEFAULT, 0,
                              NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);
    ShowWindow(hwndWindow, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
    UpdateWindow(hwndWindow);

    MSG msg;
    HACCEL hAccelTable = LoadAccelerators(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(109));

    // Main message loop:
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) {
        if (!TranslateAccelerator(msg.hwnd, hAccelTable, &msg)) {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This code worked fine for me (Windows 10): 
[image]

But if it running on Windows 7, after quickly drag and move the windows so that it "go out of" the screen: 
[image]

And this is the result after move the window back into screen:
[image]

In this case, `assert(bmp != nullptr)` will fall and the program exit suddenly.
This does not happen on Windows 10!

Why `CreateDIBitmap` return null in this case???

Comment: `SelectObject(imageDC, (HGDIOBJ)imageBmpOld);` followed by `DeleteDC(imageDC);` and a final `DeleteObject((HGDIOBJ)imageBmpOld);` is a fairly fatal bug. Have a look into [device contexts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183553.aspx) for a good introduction. There are more bugs in your code (lots of bugs even). You should consider reading a book, like Petzold's [Programming Windows®, Fifth Edition](https://www.amazon.com/dp/157231995X).

Comment: Thanks for your help, @IInspectable. I will reading more about Win32 programming

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SelectObject` doesn't create a handle. In the function below you don't create `imageBmpOld` and you are not responsible for destroying it. But you did create `bitImage` (it is created in `ConvertCVMatToBMP`) and you should destroy `bitImage` at the end.

```
// Attach image to windows
void attachImage()
{
    HBITMAP bitImage = (HBITMAP)ConvertCVMatToBMP(imgMat);
    ...
    HBITMAP imageBmpOld = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(imageDC, (HGDIOBJ)bitImage);
    ...
    SelectObject(imageDC, imageBmpOld);
    DeleteDC(imageDC);
    //DeleteObject((HGDIOBJ)imageBmpOld); <<== remove this line
    DeleteObject(bitImage); //add this
    EndPaint(hwndWindow, &ps);
}
```

Cleanup for `GetDC` is done by `ReleaseDC`, not `DeleteDC`

```
HBITMAP ConvertCVMatToBMP(cv::Mat frame)
{
    ...    
    auto dc = GetDC(nullptr);
    assert(dc != nullptr && "Failure to get DC");
    auto bmp = CreateDIBitmap(dc, 
                    &headerInfo, CBM_INIT, frame.data, &bitmapInfo, DIB_RGB_COLORS);
    assert(bmp != nullptr && "Failure creating bitmap from captured frame");
    //DeleteDC(dc); <<== remove
    ReleaseDC(nullptr, dc); //<<== add
    ...
}
```

Your window procedure doesn't always return a value.  Add `return 0;` at the end.

The function `attachImage()` does not attach the image to window. It only paints the image on window. The way you have set it up it only works in response to `WM_PAINT` so you should really rename it `OnPaint()`

Also `FindWindow(NULL, title)` is not reliable because more than one window can have the same title. You should use `GetConsoleWindow` to get that window handle:

```
int main()
{
    HWND hwndConsole = GetConsoleWindow();
    ...
}
```

Better yet, you could use `WinMain` entry point to skip the console window. The easiest way is to create a new project in your IDE, it should let you select "win32 project" (not "win32 console project")

```
//int main()
int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE, LPTSTR, int)
{
    ...
}
```